# Why does the surv_pvalue (or any other) function not work inside a custom function in R?

Tags: r, survminer

To generate p-values for the differences between two survival curves, I need to perform a tedious series of steps, which need to be repeated with all combinations of two out of three values that are represented in one column of the starting data frame, say groups A, B and C:

```
# Load packages
library(survival)
library(survminer)

# Generate practice dataset
surv_time <- sample(100:200, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
surv_group <- sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
surv_status <- rep(1, 50)
surv_data <- data.frame(Time = as.numeric(surv_time), Group = surv_group,
                        Status = surv_status)

# Manual for combination of groups A and B
s_data_AB <- surv_data[surv_data$Group %in% c("A", "B"), ]
s_obj_AB <- Surv(s_data_AB$Time, s_data_AB$Status)
s_curve_AB <- survfit(s_obj_AB ~ Group, data = s_data_AB)
s_pval_AB <- surv_pvalue(s_curve_AB)
s_pval_AB
```

This works perfectly fine, but it is inconvenient to do this separately for (A+C) and (B+C). So I tried to automate this with the following custom function:

```
# Custom function
s_curve_fun <- function(groups_of_interest) {
  s_data <- surv_data[surv_data$Group %in% groups_of_interest, ]
  s_obj <- Surv(s_data$Time, s_data$Status)
  s_curve <- survfit(s_obj ~ Group, data = s_data)
  print(s_curve)
  s_pval <- surv_pvalue(s_curve)
  return(s_pval)
}

# Execute function
s_curve_fun(c("A", "B"))
```

This throws an error after the print call works, as calling the `surv_pvalue` function at the end throws the following error:

```
Error in eval(fit$call$data) : object 's_data' not found
```

Interestingly, calling the function survfit right beforehand works fine, even though `survfit` also uses the object s_data. When I export the output of `survfit` from s_curve_fun and use it as input for `surv_pvalue`, I get the same error. When I define s_data outside of s_curve_fun, everything works (but obviously not for the desired Group combination).

I am very curious to understand why this does not work and how to fix it. I'd appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not calling `survfit` in the manner it was intended. The `Surv`-object should have the column names, but not the dataset name in it.

You also need to provide `survminer::surv_pvalue` a dataset as a second parameter

Try (works for me):

```
s_curve_fun <- function(groups_of_interest) {
    s_data <- surv_data[surv_data$Group %in% groups_of_interest, ]
    # s_obj <- Surv(s_data$Time, s_data$Status)  
    # Not good to build Surv object outside survfit call
    # also not good to use `$data`
    s_curve <- survfit( Surv(Time, Status) ~ Group, data = s_data)
    print(s_curve)
    # need a data object to give to surv_pvalue
    s_pval <- surv_pvalue(s_curve, s_data)
    return(s_pval)
   }
```

Using construction of `Surv`-objects outside of the `survfit` call and giving it arguments using `$`-extraction from data objects that are outside the function screws up where `survfit` and its associated functions expect to find their environment contents and do evaluations. I'm not sure whether that widespread but error-prone practice of creating `Surv`-objects outside the calling environment of `survfit` comes from. Looking at the code for `surv_pvalue`, I'm wondering if that might be a problem in that calling framework as well.

Comment: Yup, that works perfectly. Excellent, very helpful answer. I still don't understand, though, why the sloppy way I had concocted before works "manually", i.e. outside of a custom function, but not within one. What is the structural difference between `surv_pvalue(s_curve_AB)` in the global environment and `surv_pvalue(s_curve)` within `s_curve_fun`?

Comment: I did my best to explain my understanding of “why”. If you want a greater chance of getting a real R expert to address the question then subscribe and post a MCVE at the the Rhelp mailing list.

Comment: Ah, good suggestion. Thank you for your help!